# How to split string based on regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split these lines:

> Germany/France/Italy
>
> Apple/Orange/Melon
>
> Beef/Pork
>
> iPhone/Android

Into:

> ['Germany/France/Italy']
>
> ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Melon']
>
> ['Beef/Pork']
>
> ['iPhone', 'Android']

I know I have to use split with regex, but I don't know how to use that properly.
I really appreciate it if you tell me to make it.

Comment: Why should the first and third lines keep the slash, but not the second and fourth ones? Depending on what you need, `str.split('/')` might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be using string method `split()` which takes as a parameter `sep` which is a character based on which the string will be splited. And returns a list of splitted elements. When used with no `sep` argument the string would be converted to list. 
But more elegant use would be to use `list()` method instead this method converts string to list object.

```
countries = Germany/France/Italy
fruits = Apple/Orange/Melon
meet = Beef/Pork
phones = iPhone/Android

print(list(countries))
print(fruits.split(sep='/')
print(list(meet))
print(phones.split(sep='/')
```